# How can I build and run the byteball desktop app?

Tags: nw.js, node-sqlite3

I know we should run the byteball app with nw.js framework for desktop.
So I did like below.
1. git clone
2. bower install
3. npm install
4. grunt

After these, I started the app with `nwjs .` on MacOS.
At this moment, it says:

```
module.js:365
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 

'/Users/dev/Documents/work/byteball/byteball/node_modules/byteballcore/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v0.14.7-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:363:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:309:25)
at Module.require (module.js:391:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous>

  (/Users/dev/Documents/work/byteball/byteball/node_modules/byteballcore/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:437:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:381:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:338:12)
at Module.require (module.js:391:17)
```

For these bug, there is solution on byteball repository like https://github.com/byteball/byteball

So I found the `node-v47-darwin-x64` directory, but I didn't find it.
For now, I can start the byteball desktop app but can't enter to main screen because it is stopped when I click the `continue` button and can't debug this.
How can I run this app in desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I do on linux:

```
cp -ir node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v*-linux-x64 node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-webkit-v$NW_VERSION-linux-x64
```

You have to create a copy with the NW version you are using. The byteball README says copy as `node-webkit-v0.14.7-darwin-x64` but that assumes you have NW 0.14.7 installed.

If you want to debug the app, you will need the SDK version of NW.js:
https://dl.nwjs.io/v0.14.7/nwjs-sdk-v0.14.7-osx-x64.zip

Comment: So, do I need to install sqlite3 version 0.14.7?
And how can I debug with nwjs sdk source?

Comment: Can I use nwjs from SDK  folder?

Comment: no, you don't have to install sqlite3 v0.14.7. You just make copy of the sqlite lib that was installed during `npm install`. See the copy command in my answer.

Comment: you can debug the wallet by right-clicking in the wallet window and select "Inspect background page" from the popup.

Comment: When I install the node modules with `npm install`, only one directory is made in the node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding. So , do I need to create new directory named `node-webkit-v0.14.7-darwin-x64`?  And copy `node_sqlite3.node` file there?

Comment: I tried many times but I failed to run on the desktop.
I hope you would help me with teamviewer or another way. :)

Comment: you create a directory `node-webkit-v0.14.7-darwin-x64` and copy that file you mentioned there. (Assuming you downloaded NW 0.14.7) . Did you try that and still didn't work? What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Peter Miklos.
I solved this issue.
Before,I followed the README but I failed.
Because I used the higher node.js version.
At that time,I used node 8.9.4.
For now, I downgrade the node version to 5.12.0 as was mentioned in README.
After downgrade and did the `npm install`, there is produced `node-v47-darwin-x64` directory. But when I used the node 8.9.4, there was produced `node-v57-darwin-x64` directory. So even though I copied and make 'node-webkit-v0.14.7-darwin-x64', it was not executed.
For now, it works well...
Thanks for your time.